# How can i merge the translations from one .po file into the source on another .po file?

Tags: translation

I'm creating a survey in several different languages and so have two .po files, one has the questions and the other has the translations. I wanted to combine the files so the translations are copied across, but am only able to copy them across manually one at a the moment.

There isn't a common key between them so wasn't sure if there was a more efficient way to do it, or even if i could bulk copy them over?

hope someone can help!